# css3 transtion not working with v-for in vue2

Tags: css, vue.js

I use transtion in vue2. I added transition in css. Vue template show two box. One way use v-for and array, another way is use variable. btn2 is effective but btn1 not.

```
<style lang="sass">
    .item
        width: 120px
        height: 120px
        background-color: bisque
        transition: margin-left 500ms
</style>
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="item" v-for="item in list" :key="item.index" :style="{marginLeft: item.index + 'px'}">{{ item.value }}</div>
        <div class="item" :style="{marginLeft: left + 'px'}">123</div>
        <button @click="addone">btn1</button>
        <button @click="addtwo">btn2</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Heap',
        data() {
            return {
                left: 100,
                list: [
                    {
                        value: 12,
                        index: 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addone() {
                this.list[0]['index']+=10
            },
            addtwo() {
                this.left+=10
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the code `:key="item.index"` on your first div. Your code then updates that same index.

When a key's value changes, the component it is attached to re-renders. You are not seeing the animation occur because instead of dynamically incrementing the CSS, you are effectively just re-rendering the element with the new CSS.

The purpose of a key is to help Vue keep track of the identity of a given node in a list. It lets Vue know which nodes it can keep and patch up and which ones need to be rendered again.

You should use a static, non-changing value as a key where possible. In the following example I have added an `id` property to your object and used that as the key.

```
<style lang="sass">
.item
  width: 120px
  height: 120px
  background-color: bisque
  transition: margin-left 500ms
</style>
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="item in list"
      :key="item.id"
      class="item"
      :style="{marginLeft: item.index.toString() + 'px'}"
    >
      {{ item.value }}
    </div>
    <div class="item" :style="{marginLeft: left.toString() + 'px'}">123</div>
    <button @click="addone">btn1</button>
    <button @click="addtwo">btn2</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Example',
  data() {
    return {
      left: 100,
      list: [
        {
          id: '1',
          value: 12,
          index: 10,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addone() {
      this.list[0].index += 10;
    },
    addtwo() {
      this.left += 10;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```